Issue with Reinitializing Cropper After Adding Image with Dropzone
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var cropper;

    $(document).ready(function() {

   $('#cropperModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log('---shown.bs.modal-----');
    //var $image = $('#modalImage');
    let imageElm = document.getElementById('modalImage');
    let section = $('#modalImage').data('section');
    $(imageElm).show();
    console.log(section);
    let aspectRatio = getAspectRatio(section);
    console.log('---shown.bs.modal---- aspectRatio: ' & aspectRatio);
    cropper = new Cropper(imageElm, {
     viewMode: 2,
     responsive: true,
     ready: function() {
      let cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
      console.log(cropBoxData);
      let naturalWidth = imageElm.naturalWidth;
      let naturalHeight = imageElm.naturalHeight;
      console.log('naturalWidth ' & naturalWidth);
      cropBoxData.width = naturalWidth;
      cropBoxData.height = naturalHeight;
      cropper.setCropBoxData(cropBoxData);
   },
  crop: function(event) {
    /*console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);*/
    }
  });
  }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    // Destroy the cropper instance when the modal is hidden
    if (cropper) {
      cropper.destroy();
      cropper = null;
    }
  });

$('#upload-header, #upload-horizontal, #upload-logo').on('click', function() {
    let section = $(this).data('section');
    let imageUrl = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    openModalAndInitializeDropzone(section, imageUrl);
  });


  $('#cropperModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log('hidden.bs.modal');
    resetDropzone("#hidden-dropzone");
    $('#modalImage').attr('src', '').hide();
    $('#upload-button').hide();
  });

  $('#save-changes-button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('save changes button clicked');
    saveCroppedImage(cropper);
  });

  function getAspectRatio(section) {
    console.log('getAspectRatio ' + section);
    switch (section) {
      case 'header':
        return 16 / 9;
      case 'horizontal':
        return 4 / 3;
      case 'logo':
        return 1 / 1;
      default:
        return 1 / 1;
    }
  }


  function openModalAndInitializeDropzone(section, imageUrl) {
    $('#cropperModal').modal('show');
    $('#modalImage').attr('src', imageUrl).data('section', section).show();

    initializeDropzone("#hidden-dropzone", getAspectRatio(section),
      function(cropperInstance) {
        cropper = cropperInstance;
      });
  }

  function initializeDropzone(dropzoneId, aspectRatio, cropCallback) {
    console.log('initializeDropzone called');
    if (Dropzone.instances.length > 0) {
      Dropzone.instances.forEach(instance => instance.destroy());
     if (cropper) {
        cropper.destroy();
        cropper = null;
     }
    }
   
    let dropzone = new Dropzone(dropzoneId, {
      url: "/file/post",
      maxFilesize: 2,
      acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png",
      maxFiles: 1,
      init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {

          console.log('addedfile called');
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(event) {
            console.log('reader.onload called');
            $('#modalImage').off('load'); // Unbind the previous load event
            $('#modalImage').attr('src', event.target.result).show(); // Load image into modal
            $('#modalImage').on('load', function() {
              //alert('test');
              cropCallback(initializeCropper('#modalImage', aspectRatio));
            });
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
        this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
          file.previewElement.remove();
        });
      }
    });
    // Ensure the Dropzone area is visible in the modal
    $(dropzoneId).css({
      display: 'block',
      width: '100%',
      height: '200px',
      border: '2px dashed #007bff',
      padding: '20px',
      textAlign: 'center',
      lineHeight: '160px',
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: '#007bff'
    }).text('Drag and drop an image here or click to upload');
  }

  function resetDropzone(dropzoneId) {
    let dropzoneElement = Dropzone.forElement(dropzoneId);
    if (dropzoneElement) {
      dropzoneElement.removeAllFiles(true);
    }
  }

  function initializeCropper(imageId, aspectRatio) {
    alert('initializeCropper called');
    var $image = $(imageId);
    var section = $image.data('section');
    var aspectRatio = getAspectRatio(section);
    let imageElm = document.getElementById('modalImage');
    console.log(imageElm);
    if ($image.length) {
      if (cropper) {
        cropper.destroy(); // Destroy the previous Cropper instance
        cropper = null;
      }
      
      console.log('Initializing cropper...');
      console.log($image);
      $image.cropper({
         viewMode: 2,
         responsive: true,
        /*aspectRatio: aspectRatio,*/
        crop: function(e) {
          console.log('Crop event:', e);
        },
      ready: function() {
        console.log(cropper);
        let cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
        console.log(cropBoxData);
        let naturalWidth = imageElm.naturalWidth;
        let naturalHeight = imageElm.naturalHeight;
        console.log('naturalWidth ' & naturalWidth);
        cropBoxData.width = naturalWidth;
        cropBoxData.height = naturalHeight;
        cropper.setCropBoxData(cropBoxData);
   }
      });
      $('#upload-button').show();
      return $image.data('cropper');
    }

    console.error('Image element not found:', imageId);
    return null;
  }

  function saveCroppedImage(cropper, width, height) {
    if (cropper) {
      var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
        width: width,
        height: height
      });

      if (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'croppedImage.' + blob.type.split('/')[1]);

          $.ajax('/main/uploadFile', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(response) {
              $('#status-gyph-image').html('<strong>Successfully uploaded images.</strong>').addClass('text-success').removeClass('text-danger');
              console.log('Upload success:', response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              $('#status-gyph-image').html('An internal error occurred.').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('text-success');
              console.error('Upload error:', error, xhr);
            }
          });
        });
      } else {
        $('#status-gyph-image').html('An internal error occurred.').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('text-success');
        console.error('Canvas is null. Cropper might not be properly initialized.');
      }
    } else {
      $('#status-gyph-image').html('An internal error occurred.').addClass('text-danger').removeClass('text-success');
      console.error('Cropper instance is not initialized.');
       }
      }
    });


I click “Drag and drop an image here or click to upload,” then select my image file.
The image is successfully added, and Cropper initializes correctly.
I click “Drag and drop an image here or click to upload” again, select another image file, but this time Cropper does not initialize. the image appears, but there is no Cropper.. I am expecting this to work the 2nd time and beyond that I add an image, not just the first time.

